# How to select required database and particular schema from selected database from DB2 during run time using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, db2

I have created many databases in db2 and i want to select particular database during 'run time' for processing and also from that selected database i have to select required schema using JDBC. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) StackOverflow users are not there to do everything in your place. You should ask a more specific question showing that you made some efforts to search for answers by yourself first : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tip: the database name is in the connection string. If you have further questions, try to be more detailed in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a JDBC Connection you can use `Connection.setCatalog(String)` and `Connection.setSchema(String)` to switch the current database or schema.

Comment: @LaxmikanthMadhyastha -- if the answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for good karma.